# BufferedReader Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bufferedreader

I am trying to use BufferedReader in Java to read a file named hello.txt of ASCII characters from my Documents folder.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String  thisLine = null;
  try{
     // open input stream test.txt for reading purpose.
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("c:/hello.txt");
     while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(thisLine);
     }       
  }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Test.java:12: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Reader
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("c:/hello.txt");
                                            ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to          get full output
1 error
```

I assume I am writing the arguments of BufferedReader wrong, but I am not sure what exactly?

Comment: [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

Comment: There is no constructor of `BufferedReader` that takes a `String` as parameter

Comment: Use `java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get('c:/hello.txt'))`.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)? Instead of just guessing?

Answer (score 3):

`BufferReader` takes `Reader` as an argument, not a `String`.

From the [Java official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), the available constructors are,

```
BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)
BufferedReader(Reader in)
```

There is no such constructor as,

```
BufferedReader(String s)
```

You need to do something as follows,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\hello.txt"));
```

or,

```
File f = new File("c:\hello.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the below

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/hello.txt"));
```

BufferedReader expects a Reader as argument, hence the error

Comment: `BufferedReader` expects a `Reader` as an argument.